# ¿Por qué mi while no se cumple?

Tags: javascript, while

```js
let again
let puntos= 0
let aciertos=0
/*
alert('Bienvenido a Preguntados! Este juego consistirá en que tendrás que responder dos preguntas correctas de cada una de las 5 categorías que tiene este juego para ganar.') 
alert('Las preguntas tienen puntos, y mientras más puntos tengan, más difícil será la pregunta.') 
alert('Cada categoría es más difícil que la anterior, y para poder pasar de categoría en categoría, tendrás que responder dos preguntas correctamente de esa categoría.') 
alert('Ganas si conestatas 10 preguntas correctas en total, en cada categoría tendrás tres oportunidades de fallar, si fallas una cuarta vez, habrás perdido.')  */
let name = prompt('Antes de iniciar, ¿Cómo te llamas?')
do {
    do {
        alert(name+', la primera categoría es Entretenimiento')
        let entretenimiento1 = prompt('Elige el valor de tu pregunta (puedes elegir entre 100, 200, 300, 400 y 500)')
        if(entretenimiento1 == '100'){
            let entretenimiento100 = prompt ('¿Cómo se llama la cuarta película de Harry Potter? El cáliz de fuego, el misterio del príncipe, la piedra filosofal o la orden del Fénix (Responde 1, 2, 3 o 4)')
            if (entretenimiento100 == 1 ){
                alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento1+' puntos.')
                puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1);    
                let aciertos= aciertos+1;
                alert (aciertos)
            }
        }else if(entretenimiento1 == '200'){
            let entretenimiento200 = prompt ('¿Cómo se llama el personaje de la mejor amiga de Mia Thermopolis en la película "El Diario de la Princesa"? Lilly, Emma, Anna, Bonny (Responde 1,2,3 o 4    ')
            if (entretenimiento200 == 1 ){
                alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento1+' puntos.')  
                puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1);
                let aciertos = aciertos+1
                alert (aciertos)
            }
        }else if(entretenimiento1 == '300'){
            let entretenimiento300 = prompt (' ¿Quién es la artista más joven en ganar un premio Country?  Dolly Parton, Miley Cyrus, Taylor Swift, Carrie Underwood (Responde 1, 2, 3, 4)    ')
            if (entretenimiento300 == 3 ){
                alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento1+' puntos.')
                puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1);
                let aciertos = aciertos +1
                alert (aciertos)
            }
        }else if(entretenimiento1 == '400'){
            let entretenimiento400 = prompt (' ¿Quién es el creador del talent show "The X Factor"? Louis Walsh, Simon Cowell, Sharon Osbourne, Nicole Scherzinger   ')
            if (entretenimiento400 == 2 ){
                alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento1+' puntos.')
                puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1);
                let aciertos= aciertos+1
                alert (aciertos)
            }
        }else if(entretenimiento1 == '500'){
            let entretenimiento500 = prompt (' ¿En qué año se estrenó la película de Disney "Pinocho"? 1940, 1944, 1930, 1960    ')
            if (entretenimiento500 == 1 ){
                alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la primera pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento1+' puntos.')
                puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento1);
                let aciertos = aciertos+1
                alert (aciertos)
            }   
        }else{
            alert('Opción no válida, el juego se reiniciará')
        }
    } while ( aciertos> 3)

    again = confirm('¿Quiéres volver a jugar?')
} while (again)
```

Okay bueno aquí hice un código para que sea un juego tipo preguntados. Al final habrá más categorías y pues hay sumatoria de puntos y categorías. Se supone que apenas estoy en la primera categoría y pues no puede pasar a la siguiente si no tiene dos aciertos correctos, y se tiene solo 3 oportunidades para sacar la pregunta correcta. El problema es que ya hice que se sumen los aciertos y puse un 'while' al final de la función entretenimiento pero parece no ser suficiente. De todos modos me dice que si quiero volver a jugar en vez de hacerlo algo obligatorio. También puse un 'alert' para saber los aciertos que llevaba pero parece que tampoco funciona.

Comment: La función `confirm` devuelve un booleano, por lo cual deberías poner false como valor por defecto en `let again`. Quedaría así `let again = false` y dependiendo de si das aceptar o cancelar el valor de `again` cambiara de true o se quedara en false;

Comment: Tienes fallos sintácticos en tu código, revisa los ";"

Answer (score 6):

Al parecer no esta muy bien pensado.

Fijate que la cantidad de acierto nunca va a ser mayor que 1.
Pongamos un ejemplo tal cual esta escrito el codigo:

Supongamos que empiezo a jugar y elijo la categoria 1. Aqui hay dos caminos

1. Contesto correctamente: En este caso la cantidad de aciertos seria 1, luego llegaria a evaluar la condicion del while(aciertos > 3) y esto no se cumple, con lo cual ejecutara la pregunta de volver a jugar
2. Contesto incorrectamente: En este caso la cantidad de aciertos queda en 0, pasa lo mismo que el caso anterior ya que el while no se cumple.

Me parece que lo que estas intentando hacer es repetir la misma pregunta a lo sumo 3 veces, para esto tendrias que contar la cantidad de veces que le erra a la respuesta, por lo cual deberias agregar un else a tus if's y hacer el while con respecto a eso.

Dale una vuelta mas que sale rapido.

Espero haya servido!

Abrazo!

Answer (score 5):

Vamos por partes:

Primero el bucle:

```
let aciertos = 0;
... //más código por aquí
do {
  ...
} while (aciertos > 3);
```

El bucle se repite mientras se cumpla que `aciertos > 3`, lo que nunca ocurre porque empieza siendo cero y en cada iteración sólo se aumenta en 1 (si se acierta la respuesta). Lo que quieres es hasta 3 intentos, y eso lo pondría así:

```
let intentos = 0;

do {
  ...
  intentos++; //equivalente a intentos = intentos + 1
} while (intentos < 3);
```

Por otro lado, tienes un bloque `if.. else if... else if...` que repite mucho código. Básicamente es siempre lo siguiente:

```
let entretenimiento = prompt ('Pregunta')
if (entretenimiento == 2 ){
   alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la  pregunta. Tienes ' +entretenimiento+' puntos.')
   puntos += parseInt(entretenimiento);
   aciertos = aciertos + 1;
}
```

Podríamos guardar las preguntas y respuestas en una estructura y reutilizar ese trozo de código:

```js
let again;
let puntos= 0;
let intentos=0;

let preguntas = {
  '100' : {
    pregunta : '¿Cómo se llama la cuarta película de Harry Potter? El cáliz de fuego, el misterio del príncipe, la piedra filosofal o la orden del Fénix (Responde 1, 2, 3 o 4)',
    respuesta : 1
  },
  
  '200' : {
    pregunta: '¿Cómo se llama el personaje de la mejor amiga de Mia Thermopolis en la película "El Diario de la Princesa"? Lilly, Emma, Anna, Bonny (Responde 1,2,3 o 4)',
    respuesta : 1
  }
  //más preguntas y respuestas aquí
  
}

let name = prompt('Antes de iniciar, ¿Cómo te llamas?')
do {
    do {
        alert(name+', la primera categoría es Entretenimiento')
        let valor = prompt('Elige el valor de tu pregunta (puedes elegir entre 100, 200, 300, 400 y 500)')
        let seleccion = preguntas[valor];
        if (seleccion === undefined) {
            alert('Opción no válida');
        } else {
          let respuesta = + prompt(seleccion.pregunta); //el + transforma a números
          if (respuesta === seleccion.respuesta) {
            puntos += (+valor);
            alert('¡Felicidades '+name+', has respondido correctamente la pregunta. Tienes ' +puntos+' puntos.');
          } else {
            alert('¡Lo siento '+name+', has respondido incorrectamente la pregunta. Tienes ' +puntos+' puntos.');
          }
          intentos++;
        }
          
    } while ( intentos < 3)

    again = confirm('¿Quieres volver a jugar?')
} while (again)
```

Ahora lógica es más pequeña (por tanto más entendible) y añadir más preguntas sólo requiere tocar la variable `preguntas`, no requiere un nuevo `if`